# How to encrypt a gzip file in python

Tags: python, encryption, gzip

I am a new bee to python, and I am working on an application that requires to gzip the file [in order to reduce the size of the file as the encryption I am using doesnt handle data when it is > 2GB] and then encrypt it. I was able to gzip the text file thus bringing down the size. Then, read the file content without `gzip.open` and sent the data for encryption. After encryption, I have to again write it to gzip file, which means it will be again gzipped again [gzipping the encrypted data]. But this would be wrong. My intention is gzip the file, then encrypt it and send the encrypted data in a file to the destination location.

Any suggestions here on how can I achieve this? basically, i want to gzip the file and encrypt the gzipped data, and write back to a file. So the receiver can de-crypt the data and ungzip it to extract the plain data.

Below is my code I tried:

```
def ungzip():
    file_name = "/tmp/mygzipdata.json.gz"
    json_data = "some json content"
    try:
       with gzip.open(file_name, 'wb') as output_file:
            json.dump(json_data, output_file, indent=4, default=default)

       gzip_file_contents = open(file_name, 'rb')
       data = gzip_file_contents.read()
       ## my encryption code, where I will be encrypting "data"
       gzip_file_contents.close()
       gzip_file_contents = gzip.open(file_name, 'wb')
       gzip_file_contents.write(encrypted_data)
       gzip_file_contents.close()

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: Open it with regular `open`, not `gzip.open` when writing the encrypted contents? There's no reason to gzip the encrypted data; if the encryption algorithm is worth a damn, the resulting data should be effectively random bytes, with compression providing little or no benefit (possibly even increasing the file size).

Comment: what encryption module are you using?

Comment: encryption used is a internal client about which I cannot divulge much

Comment: @ShadowRanger: I used regular `open` and not `gzip.open` with `rb` as mode will ungzip the file right? I know, opening the gzip file with regular 'open' may be stupid way, but I dont know the right approach.

Comment: @user3624000: I'm not sure what you're asking... The sequence should be 1) Read original data with `open` 2) Write original data with `gzip.open` 3) Read gzipped data with `open` to get the compressed bytes 4) Encrypt 5) Write encrypted bytes with `open`. Decryption is the reverse: 1) Read encrypted with `open`, 2) Decrypt, 3) Write with `open` to dump gzipped data to disk 4) Open with `gzip.open` to read decompressed data 5) Write w/`open` to write uncompressed data. Steps #2 and #3 in encrypt, and #3 and #4 in decrypt may be combinable to avoid dumping to disk, but for starters, do 'em all.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Oh.. I missed that. Basically, I should modify the #5 in encrypt. ie) change `gzip.open` to just regular `open`. Then, that is enough ?

Comment: @Barmar: Why do you think so? Why not without `with`? Please help me understand.

Comment: Because it's better style. It ensures that the file will always be closed even if an exception is signaled. Why did you use it with `gzip.open()` but not `open()`?

Comment: @Barmar: You mean this line `gzip_file_contents = gzip.open(file_name, 'wb')`. It was a miss from my end [brain fade probably]. I should have used `gzip_file_contents = open(file_name, 'wb')`

Comment: Yes, I'm recommending that you use `with open(file_name, "rb") as gzip_file_contents:`

Comment: @Barmar: Yeah, that is right. Will do. Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: @user3624000: Yup.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Thank you so much :)